# How can I prevent a command from using specific windows?

Tags: buffers, window

Typically, I have a frame split into four windows, where two at the bottom are dedicated to my `*compilation*` and `*grep*` buffers. When browsing compilation errors, `next-error` will eventually replace my `*grep*` buffer with one of the target file.

**How can I configure `next-error` to *not* use the window containing the `*grep*` buffer?**

My specific use-case is the `next-error` command, but more general answers are welcome as well.

Comment: Related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/327/how-can-i-block-a-frame-from-being-split/338#338

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I second @Nsukami's suggestion to use [dedicated windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html). Since it is a [function, not a command](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3555/504), using `set-window-dedicated-p` directly can be cumbersome. With the following command and associated key binding, you can toggle "dedicatedness" of any window by pressing <kbd>C-c t</kbd>:

```el
(defun toggle-window-dedicated ()
  "Control whether or not Emacs is allowed to display another
buffer in current window."
  (interactive)
  (message
   (if (let (window (get-buffer-window (current-buffer)))
         (set-window-dedicated-p window (not (window-dedicated-p window))))
       "%s: Can't touch this!"
     "%s is up for grabs.")
   (current-buffer)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t") 'toggle-window-dedicated)
```

Comment: Now that's a convenient way to use this dedicated window feature! Thanks, it works like a charm.

Comment: indeed, better inside a function+keybing.

Answer (score 5):

May I suggest [dedicated-window](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html#Dedicated-Windows)?

You'll have to dedicate windows to buffers using this function:

**set-window-dedicated-p window flag:** This function marks window as dedicated to its buffer if flag is non-nil, and non-dedicated otherwise.

Courtesy of [gnu](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html#Dedicated-Windows)