# How do I force a specific buffer to open in a new window?

Tags: buffers, window, magit

When committing changes in Magit, it is useful to have the diff view open while adding details about the commit.

In Magit, we see the diff in the `*magit ..*` buffer. When you hit <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> while the cursor is on a *Staged* file, the Magit commit buffer `.. COMMIT_EDITMSG` pops up. By default, this new buffer replaces the `*magit ..*` buffer that was showing the commit diffs.

**QUESTION -**
How do I make the `.. COMMIT_EDITMSG` buffer open in a new window (reuse a different window or create a new window if the frame had just 1 window to begin with) so that I can see both the `*magit ..*` and `.. COMMIT_EDITMSG` buffers?

Comment: Related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/327/50

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is possible to configure how a buffer opens (in the same frame/window or a different frame/window) using `display-buffer-alist`. Refer to the references below to learn more about this variable.

### Solution

We need to tell emacs to always open buffers ending with `COMMIT_EDITMSG` in a window but not in the same (`*magit ..*`) window.

Add the following snippet to the `init.el` after `(require 'magit)` to specify this action.

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
                 '(".*COMMIT_EDITMSG". ((display-buffer-pop-up-window) .
                                        ((inhibit-same-window . t)))))
```

### Breakdown of the solution

`display-buffer-alist` is an [`alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html) that calls a `FUNCTION` (or a list of functions) with `ALIST` parameters when a `CONDITION` is true. The `display-buffer-alist` can be represented as,

```
'(CONDITION . (FUNCTION . ALIST))
```

- Here `CONDITION` is that the buffer name ends with `COMMIT_EDITMSG` and that is represented by `".*COMMIT_EDITMSG"`.
- The `FUNCTION` to call is `display-buffer-pop-up-window` as we want to create a window for this buffer. Instead of specifying the function by itself it's put in as a list of a single function `(display-buffer-pop-up-window)`so that more functions can be easily added to the list if needed in future.
- The `ALIST` contains `(inhibit-same-window . t)` as we don't want this buffer to open in the same window.

### References

- Variable [display-buffer-alist](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var/display-buffer-alist.html)
- Function [display-buffer](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/display-buffer.html)
- Function [display-buffer-pop-up-window](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/display-buffer-pop-up-window.html)
- Related emacs SE question: [How can I block a frame from being split?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/327/how-can-i-block-a-frame-from-being-split)

Answer (score 2):

Starting with `v2.1.0` Magit by default shows the changes that are being committed alongside the buffer used to write the commit message.