# When switching buffers, prevent emacs from automatically switching frame

Tags: buffers, frames, ido, navigation

When I switch buffers, emacs will switch to an existing frame if the buffer is already opened there.

I found how to prevent that when switching with ido using :

```
(setq ido-default-buffer-method 'selected-window)
```

But it's not enough : for exemple if there's a lisp error emacs will automatically switch to the buffer *Backtrace*, and will switch frames if it's already open.

Is there a way to prevent completely emacs from switching to an existent frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There does not appear to be an option for this.

The function to find a buffer *does* allow you to specify whether to look in all frames or only in the current frame:

```
(get-buffer-window &optional BUFFER-OR-NAME ALL-FRAMES)
```

However, the implementation of `switch-to-buffer` passes 0 for the `ALL-FRAMES` argument, which means it will look in all frames.

I suppose you could use `:around` advice with `get-buffer-window` to replace that argument, if you truly wanted to globally prevent this behavior... but I suspect that would break other things.

Comment: That's what I feared. I might try the add-advice around get-buffer-window, but I'm not too fond of advising widely used functions.

Comment: Yeah, seems likely to cause trouble. You might want to check out the `popwin` package as a way of dealing with special buffers -- not sure if that plus the ido config you already found might be sufficient.

Comment: Actually, I may have missed the boat here. You should take a look at the Emacs manual sections on 'Choosing Window' and 'Display Action Functions'. In particular, the use of `inhibit-switch-frame` seems useful. (I have not had a chance to experiment with these options yet.)

Comment: See also: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/how-do-i-force-a-specific-buffer-to-open-in-a-new-window

Comment: Thanks, that SE thread is very helpful. The documentation for `display-buffer` and `display-buffer-alist` makes my head hurt, but it's only a question of time until I find a solution.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't quite sorted it out either. But seems like it should be possible!