# Starting SLIME in a pop-up frame

Tags: window, frames, repl, slime

Whenever I currently do `M-x slime`, it creates a split buffer, with SLIME going in the bottom half. This is not really very desirable - I'd much rather SLIME appeared in a separate frame, and kept its REPL there. Is there a way I can make it so that when I do `M-x slime`, it will create a new frame, and open the SLIME REPL there?

Comment: Related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2194/115

Comment: I believe that you want the new window to appear in a new pop-up frame as your accepted answer does that. Can you reword your question to reflect that if that's the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adjusting the value of `display-buffer-alist`:

```
(setq display-buffer-alist
      (quote (("\\*inferior-lisp\\*" display-buffer-pop-up-frame
         (nil)))))
```

This setting tells Emacs that a buffer with the name matching the regular expression "`\*inferior-lisp\*`" should be displayed in a new (pop-up) frame.

(You can also customize this variable.)