# How can I force emacs to never split frames, in particular for compile-goto-error?

Tags: window, frames, window-splitting

I want emacs to always display new buffers in the current frame, but always taking the whole frame, rather than splitting it.

I currently have customized display-buffer-alist to the following

```
'(display-buffer-alist (quote ((".*" display-buffer-same-window))))
```

This seems to work in many cases (e.g. it works for C-x C-b) but not for all cases, most notably compile-goto-error, which still splits the frame.

I've looked at documentation and other questions, including the similar [How can I block a frame from being split?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/327/how-can-i-block-a-frame-from-being-split), but I can't find a correct solution. In particular, that question uses display-buffer-reuse-window, while I'm pretty sure I want display-buffer-same-window, and also I want to have absolutely no exceptions.

Emacs version is 24.5

Comment: There is no 100% guarantee that modifying the `display-buffer-alist` will control all situations, especially if a window is **dedicated**.  The guaranteed method is to look at the source code for each situation and deal with it.  The `compile.el` library is frequently used in conjunction with other major-mode libraries, so you will need to look at both to see how displaying buffers are accomplished for a particular use-case situation.  See also the `split-width-threshold` and `split-height-threshold` variables:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Choice.html

Comment: In the event you have a **dedicated** window situation, it would be helpful to familiarize yourself with that section of the manual:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @lawlist said in a comment, you can use dedicated windows. A simple way to do this is to customize **`special-display-regexps`** to the list `(.*)`, that is, a list with a regexp that matches all buffer names.

[Do not be bothered about the fact that help about `special-display-regexps` tells you that it is "obsolete since 24.3".  It is super simple and works perfectly.    I'd be lost without it.  (Emacs tells you to just use the hypertrophied, steroidal `display-buffer-alist` instead.  Good luck with that!)]